# Table of function pointers within a class C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to make a table of function pointers within a class.  I haven't been able to find any examples of this online, most involve using member function pointers outside of their class.

for example:

```
class Test
{
    typedef void (Test::*FunctionType)();
    FunctionType table[0x100];

    void TestFunc()
    {
    }

    void FillTable()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 0x100; i++)
            table[i] = &Test::TestFunc;
    }   

    void Execute(int which)
    {
        table[which]();
    }
}test;
```

Gives me the error "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments".

Answer (score 19):

In this line in the `Execute` function:

```
table[which]();
```

You can't call it like that because it's not a normal function. You have to provide it with an object on which to operate, because it's a **pointer to a member function**, not a pointer to a function (there's a difference):

```
(this->*table[which])();
```

That will make the invoking object whichever object is pointed to by the `this` pointer (the one that's executing `Execute`).

Also, when posting errors, make sure to include the line on which the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Seth has the right answer.  Next time, look up the compiler error number on MSDN and you'll see the same:  [Compiler Error C2064](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72c1dfd.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need a context in which to call your function. In your case, the context is `this`:

```
void Execute(int which)
{
    (this->*table[which])();
}
```